# ¿Para qué crear un objeto en forma inmediata sin tener que declarar una clase?

Tags: java, poo, kotlin, objeto, intellij-idea

según un curso de kotlin que estoy siguiendo
[en esta página](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/kotlinya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=31&codigo=31&inicio=30)

porqué o en que caso que me serviría hacer un objeto sin la clase?
gracias de antemano.

> dice la página "Otra característica del lenguaje Kotlin es poder definir un objeto en forma inmediata sin tener que declarar una clase. Aparece una nueva palabra clave **object** con la que podemos crear estos objetos en forma directa."

Comment: Considera agregar la parte esencial del enlace ya que podría no servir ese enlace en un futuro y no sería de mucha ayuda a la comunidad, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: sisi, eso hice. la parte comentada es la que estoy preguntando en particular. donde escribí "dice la página "otra caracteristica... (...)" "

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta, puedes usar un object cuando creas clases,métodos,listas, etc... que son genéricos, esto quiere decir que pueden recibir objetos diferentes y realizar algo con ese objeto sin importa el tipo.
Por ejemplo

```
ArrayList<Object> objetos= new ArrayList<>();
        Estudiante estudiante = new Estudiante("Juan",1);
        Profesor profesor= new Profesor("Pedro",20,"Matematicas");
        
        objetos.add(estudiante);
        objetos.add(profesor);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < objetos.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(objetos.get(i).toString());
        }
```

En el código anterior guardamos dos objetos diferentes en un mismo arraylist poniendo como tipo Object en lugar de crear dos arrays para cada clase y son imprimidos.

```
//Lo que imprimiria en consola
    Estudiante [nombre=Juan, semestre=1]
    Profesor [nombre=Pedro, edad=20, curso=Matematicas]
```

Esto es un uso básico pero es probable que si en futuro creas clases genéricas o métodos genéricos muy probablemente uses como parámetro un object para hacer algo con eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias. muy buen ejemplo. un abrazo